# Can i edit a message sent via webRTC data channel?

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection, rtcdatachannel

Is there a way to edit any messages sent by the RTCDataChannel API for webRTC ?

Comment: Edit when you receive them? Or are you asking if there are any restrictions on what you can send?

Comment: edit the message after I send it

Comment: After it is sent the sender can't modify the message. The receiver can modify the buffer after it arrives.

Comment: thank you Sean DuBois